# Java: Set pixel color on screen without capturing mouse?

Tags: java, graphics, colors, jframe, pixel

I want to make a program that can color a pixel on the screen without capturing the mouse when it's clicked on, whilst still remaining on top of other programs open.
I have tried with JFrames but they capture the mouse whenever I click on them and i was wondering if there's a way to go about it in java.  If not then any suggestions on a language that would allow this kind of thing? (python, C#)?
Is there a way of just changing the pixel color on the screen without having any frame?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think this might be an OS limitation that cannot be overcome. OS sends a window active signal only when you click on the frame.

Comment: You should be able to do it in c++/WinAPI using [SystemHooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) With a mouse hook you can listen to any mouse event without stopping it to being passed to the underlieing window.